# In DDD, how should I model direct interaction with an external SQL Server?

Tags: .net, architecture, domain-driven-design, sqlconnection, abp

In the context of Domain Driven Design and .NET, how should I model direct interaction with a remote SQL Server (using a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`)?

I need to do things like call a stored procedure and get back an ID. Later I might need to do things like getting a list of entities and their IDs so I can create local analogues with soft references to those.

By my understanding, DDD says such functionality should be part of domain services, if while interacting with the external system we also need to check core business rules, or be part of application services if calling the external system is just a side-effect that has no bearing on preserving the core business invariants.

Domain services are closer to the core domain, while application services are a layer up from that. Here's my dilema then: where should I put this logic?

Is it okay to add a reference to `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` in my Domain project (which is where the core domain model is)? I feel bad thinking about this. I feel like this is not part of the domain service concern.

Or is better to add this reference to `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` in my Application project (which depends on Domain and holds application services) and create a specialised application service for interacting with the remote SQL Server? And then that application service will call into the domain (via a repository, or use a domain service) to locally save the remote ID after it has been created in the remote server by using `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`.

What do you recommend?

**EDIT**

I realised that my question might be too broad or I'm not giving enough information.

In my solution, which is using the ABP.io framework, I have these projects:

| Project | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Acme.Bomb.Domain | Core domain model, contains aggregates, entities and value objects. |
| Acme.Bomb.Domain.Shared | Shared kernel, contains enums, constants, utils, custom attributes, and even some shared value objects that will never change depending on context, and I didn't want to duplicate their code. |
| Acme.Bomb.EntityFrameworkCore | Contains my DbContext(s) and low lever infrastructure code for persisting data. |
| Acme.Bomb.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations | Contains database migration code specific to EF Core. |
| Acme.Bomb.HttpApi | REST API implementation, exposes application services as REST endpoints. |
| Acme.Bomb.HttpApi.Host | REST API runtime server. |
| Acme.Bomb.Application | Application layer, contains app service implementations, including simple CRUD services or services that call to other external (REST) services, repository implementations, etc. |
| Acme.Bomb.Application.Contracts | Application layer contracts, contains interface declarations for everything implemented in Acme.Bomb.Application. |

What I want to do is write an application service that uses `SqlConnection` directly, like this:

```csharp
// Project: Acme.Bomb.Application.Contracts

// File: INewCompanyRequestAppService.cs

namespace Acme.Bomb.CompanyCatalog.Aggregates
{
    public interface INewCompanyRequestAppService :
        ICrudAppService<
            NewCompanyRequestDto,
            Guid,
            PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto,
            CreateNewCompanyRequestDto,
            UpdateNewCompanyRequestDto>
    {
        Task Accept(AcceptNewCompanyRequestDto input);
        Task Reject(RejectNewCompanyRequestDto input);
    }
}
```

```csharp
// Project: Acme.Bomb.Application

// File: NewCompanyRequestAppService.cs

namespace Brokenthorn.BphNomenclatureManager.CompanyCatalog.Aggregates
{
    public class NewCompanyRequestAppService :
        CrudAppService<
            NewCompanyRequest,
            NewCompanyRequestDto,
            Guid,
            PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto,
            CreateNewCompanyRequestDto,
            UpdateNewCompanyRequestDto>,
        INewCompanyRequestAppService
    {
        // A domain service, which is not really necessary...
        // I could have done all its tasks in this app service,
        // because there is no real business logic happening in it
        // at the moment, but this is what I had refactored to
        // up to this moment of posting, so I'm including it here:
        private readonly NewCompanyRequestsManager _newCompanyRequestsManager;

        public NewCompanyRequestAppService(
            IRepository<NewCompanyRequest, Guid> newCompanyRequestsRepository,
            NewCompanyRequestsManager newCompanyRequestsManager)
            : base(newCompanyRequestsRepository)
        {
            Check.NotNull(newCompanyRequestsRepository, nameof(newCompanyRequestsRepository));
            Check.NotNull(newCompanyRequestsManager, nameof(newCompanyRequestsManager));
            
            _newCompanyRequestsManager = newCompanyRequestsManager;
        }

        public async Task Accept(AcceptNewCompanyRequestDto input)
        {
            var newCompanyRequest = await GetEntityByIdAsync(input.Id);

            // Use SqlConnection here to basically do a RPC:
            // 1. Call a stored procedure on the remote server,
            //    called sp_CreateCompany, which has a few parameters
            //    that I wil be filling using newCompanyRequest above.

            // var connection = new SqlConnection(...);
            // ... call the remote procedure
            // var remoteEntityId = ...GetValue<int>(...);

            // 2. If successful, I get back the ID of the new company
            //    as it was created on the remote system, and then
            // 3. I store this ID locally:

            // newCompanyRequest.RemoteReference = remoteEntityId;


            // 4. And now now I can call a domain service that takes care
            //    of the rest of the domain business regarding accepting
            //    a new company request:

            await _newCompanyRequestsManager.Accept(newCompanyRequest);
        }

        public Task Reject(RejectNewCompanyRequestDto input)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

So would this be "best practice" when doing DDD? At least in your opinion. I know a good developer should follow patterns are a guidance, and not... a religion.

Thank you for any help given!

Comment: The domain shouldn't know anything about SQL Server. It just knows that it needs to get data or save data. So there would typically be some abstraction like a repository interface in the domain. That's all the domain knows. The abstraction is defined in the domain, and then something outside the domain like an application service implements it.

Comment: So wait... you're saying I should define a custom repository interface in the domain, implement it in the application layer, and use that in the app or domain layer of my choosing? I thought I should write an app service that abstracts operations over the remote SQL server, just like if it would have called an external REST API directly (using an HTTP client).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on the last part of the sentence, but yes. The domain should be self-contained and not refer to things outside of itself. That allows the domain to contain logic that says, "I'm going to save this thing to a repository," but the domain doesn't know what the implementation is.

Comment: Well sounds to me like I could save me the trouble and just implement the app service to use a SqlConnection directly since a repository implementation would otherwise live in the same layer. And I don't really treat the remote server as a database or entity repository. I just need it to call a procedure and give me back a response (an ID).

Comment: The same would apply. If the operation is something that's known within the domain then there would be some abstraction so that code within the domain could say "I'm going to do X." It doesn't have to be a repository. Then the runtime implementation could interact with SQL.

Comment: @ScottHannen of course, my app service has an interface in the app contracts projects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231360/discussion-between-paul-sebastian-manole-and-scott-hannen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the context of Domain Driven Design and .NET, how should I model direct interaction with a remote SQL Server (using a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`)?

Exactly the same way you'd abstract any other infrastructure concerns. Given you seem to be connecting to an external system here I'd probably consider this an anti-corruption layer, but in the end it's just an interface defined in the `domain` and implemented in the `infrastructure` layer.

So basically you can expect to have an interface like `ISomeService` in the `domain` layer and an implementation of that interface in the `infrastructure` layer. The application service would communicate with the external system through that interface rather than using a `SqlConnection`. Make sure that the `ISomeService` abstraction is driven by business concepts rather than technical details as much as possible or else it won't be a very useful abstraction.

Have a look at the [`CollaboratorService`](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/05d95572f2ad6b85357b216d7d617b27359a360d/iddd_collaboration/src/main/java/com/saasovation/collaboration/domain/model/collaborator/CollaboratorService.java#L19) interface and [implementation](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_collaboration/src/main/java/com/saasovation/collaboration/port/adapter/service/TranslatingCollaboratorService.java) for a concrete example.

Comment: Thank you! I think everything makes sense now. Thanks a lot for offering a real example too! 